# How to guess telnet client encoding with ANSI escape codes?

Tags: python, encoding, telnet, ansi-escape

Because some telnet clients are refusing to deal with `CHARSET` negociation and also are not sending useful information when I'm requesting their environment variables, I've tried using a trick with the Device Status Report after sending some specials strings.

Binary mode is `ON`.

First, I clean the screen with `CSI+2J`, then set the cursor on first row, first column with `CSI+1;1H`.

Then I send the string `"\xc3\xa9"` which is a `UTF8` "é", and request the cursor position with CSI+6n. If the cursor has moved only one column, I'm assuming the client's encoding is `UTF8`.

Else, I send the string `"\x80\x81"`. If client's encoding is `Latin-1`, this should output nothing ; if client's encoding is `cp1252`, this should output one character, and finally if the client's encoding is Mac_Roman this should output 2 characters.

The problem is that in all cases `CSI+6n` is reporting a 2 columns move, which is incorrect when the client's encoding is not `Mac_Roman`.

Have I done something wrong or is it a known bug? Any ideas?

Edit2: Here is a working sample code, run the python script as a server and then `telnet` on `localhost 4242` to test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import SocketServer
import re

# TELNET commands we need
DO = 253
DONT = 254
WILL = 251
WONT = 252
IAC = 255
SE = 240
SB = 250
SGA = 3
ECHO = 1
BINARY = 0
NAWS = 31
LINEMODE = 34

# ANSI Escape sequence
CSI = u'\x1b['

def cmd(s):
    """Translate from TELNET commands to bytes string"""
    return b"".join([chr(x) if isinstance(x, int) else x for x in s])

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    client_charset = "ascii"

    def init_session(self):
        print "Connection from {}".format(self.client_address)
        # negotiating requested options or quit
        asking = (IAC, WILL, ECHO, IAC, WILL, SGA, IAC, DO, SGA, IAC, DO, BINARY, IAC, WILL, BINARY, IAC, WONT, LINEMODE, IAC, DONT, LINEMODE)
        waiting = set(map(cmd, [(IAC, DO, ECHO), (IAC, DO, SGA), (IAC, WILL, SGA), (IAC, WILL, BINARY), (IAC, DO, BINARY)]))
        self.request.sendall(cmd(asking))
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print [ord(x) for x in data]
        for x in waiting:
            if x not in data:
                return False
        # retrieve client's naws (terminal size)
        asking = (IAC, DO, NAWS)
        waiting = cmd((IAC, WILL, NAWS))
        self.request.sendall(cmd(asking))
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print [ord(x) for x in data]
        if waiting not in data:
            return False
        data = data.replace(chr(IAC) * 2, chr(IAC))
        waiting = cmd((IAC, SB, NAWS, r"(.)(.)(.)(.)", IAC, SE))
        r = re.search(waiting, data)
        if not r:
            return False
        a, b, c, d = ord(r.group(1)), ord(r.group(2)), ord(r.group(3)), ord(r.group(4))
        columns, rows = 256*a+b, 256*c+d
        print "%d columns, %d rows" % (columns, rows)
        self.columns, self.rows = columns, rows
        # guessing client encoding
        self.request.sendall("{0}2J{0}1;1HDeterming your encoding...".format(CSI))
        self.request.sendall("{0}2;1H\xc3\xa9{0}6n".format(CSI))
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        row, col = map(int, data[2:-1].split(";"))
        print row, col 
        if col == 2:
            self.client_charset = "utf-8"
        else:
            self.request.sendall("{0}3;1H({1}){0}6n".format(CSI, "\x80\x81"))
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            row, col = map(int, data[2:-1].split(";"))
            print row, col
            if col == 3:
                self.client_charset = "latin_1"
            elif col == 4:
                self.client_charset = "cp1252"
            elif col == 5:
                self.client_charset = "mac_roman"
        print self.client_charset
        return False # We don't handle any client
    def handle(self):
        if not self.init_session():
            print "Rejecting client"
        else:
            pass

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "", 4242

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    print "Server starting on port %d" % port

    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except:
        print "Shutting down"
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()
```

Comment: Which terminal are you doing this on? Could you show a few lines of script which allow us to attempt to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'm currently testing on osx terminal (xterm-256color) so I can switch my terminal encoding quickly.

Comment: ... And I guess `CSI="\x1B["`?  Any reason you are not using the Python curses library?

Comment: Yes CSI is "\x1b[". Regarding the curses library, I havnt been able to use it over telnet so I decided to send the ansi escape codes by myself...

Comment: Your code is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- it does not run out of the box.  If you can refactor it further so it's a free-standing script we can run in different places to observe its behavior, I would be willing to try it out and see what happens; but until then, I don't think you will receive any answers, because there is no way for us to easily test your approach.  It *seems* to me like your assumptions are sound, and the problem could easily be with e.g. the OSX Terminal rather than a fundamental problem; but again, there is no way for me to easily test it.

Comment: (... short of rewriting your code. I started, but abandoned it, because I really should be doing Real Work instead.)

Comment: Done. At least I can choose between UTF8 and ASCII and it will be enough for this kind of terminal application. Thanks for your advices anyway @tripleee!